# Javascript game development having an issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

My game I've been working on for quite a while now is running into an issue. I am ready to add in level 2 so when you complete level 1 it takes you back to the main menu. The problem is that if you try and click level one again it will not load? Is it because I'm not calling another one of my functions that I'm  supposed to? Below is some code as well as the link to my fiddle.

```
if (collides($('#nineObs'), $('#player'))) 
{
    $('#levelOne').stop();
    $('#player').css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
    $('#nineObs').css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
    $('#levelComplete').show();
    $('#levelOne').hide();
    $('#GameOver').hide();
    $("#mainMenu").show();
    $('#level2').show();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why are you doing `mainMenu`.show()?

Comment: Oh because I have it hidden whilst the game is playing and when he/she wins the game the main menu shall re appear using the jquery .show() technique

Comment: well, if you're asking why the main menu is showing, its probably because you're telling it to? I don't understand the question.

Comment: You have two `$(document).ready()` functions on the same page...that's not gonna work the way you want. You also seem to be mixing scopes with no rhyme or reason. I also don't see any event handler for clicking level one...

Comment: I actually just firgured it out It's because I needed to reset the map so he is not touching it anymore. An the problome was because once you compltete the game when ever you would click on level one again it would not work. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @JaredSmith there is nothing wrong with more than one `$(document).ready()`. It isn't necessarily great style, but it works fine.